# Should we use anything Await/Async while using prism commands?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, async-await, prism

Until today, I was thinking that when you were binding to a `DelegateCommand` with an execute method being `async`, WPF was really doing this in an `async` manner.

But according to some tests I got, and this blog post: http://brianlagunas.com/prism-delegatecommand-fromasynchandler-is-obsolete/ it was never the case.

We recently started to implement an application, and we did start to use the await/async pattern. We were thinking this would be a nice way to use `await`/`async`and have a responsive app.

So my question is: Can we use(and most important, benefits) async/await in our commands handler?

By example:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand SomeSpecificCommand { get; set; }
    public SomeViewModel(){
        SomeSpecificCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoSomeWorkAsync);
    }

    private async void DoSomeWorkAsync()
    {
        await DoSomeLongRunningJob();
        //Update the GuiWithSomething
    }
}
```

Technically this compiles, but:

1. My understanding is that XAML doesn't wait on the async return
2. If I use a `CompositeCommand`, the composite command doesn't wait on the result of the `DelegateCommand`

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use(and most important, benefits) async/await in our commands handler?

Yes, as long as your commands are fire-and-forget.

The problem is more in the testing than in production: *how do you test a view model with a command that you have no idea of when it is completed?*

One option is to "pollute" your view model with internal/public methods that are actually commands but expose the async nature, for your tests to await them.

Another one would be to reflect into the `DelegateCommand` instance to get hold of the async handler in the test.

Thirdly, you could provide your own command implementation, inspired by the `DelegateCommand`, but providing (test-)access to the async handler.

Comment: I see. The other issue I've is that the `CompositeCommand` also doesn't wait on their sub `DelegateCommand`.
And you're 100% right, my issues right now are for testing this. But since it's a `CompositeCommand` I don't even know in which ViewModel this would be called

Comment: If your DoSomeLongRunningJob() is method on an interface say IFoo, you can inject your mock and unit test them as you wish, it is perfectly normal to have methods as async even Commands also